# Glass fish Server authentication

Tags: java, servlet-filters, glassfish-4

I wrote a servlet in eclipse and Deployed it on Glass Fish server(4), and it is working no problem, now I want to create Authentication and Authorization, i was wondering if there is no  easy way i can do this using the Glass fish server without having to write code in my servlet I deployed? It's my first time working with Glass fish, any Ideas please I ll appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to write some code, but using `JAAS` can make it simpler to perform for example database based authentication. It's a bit of a read though.

Comment: Thanks JAAS works also, but I decided to use Basic Authentication anotation on my servlet and create users using Glass Fish. it seem to work.